# Predis installation and configuration

Tags: php, ubuntu, predis

I installed Predis on Ubuntu and when I try to connect I get the error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Predis\Client' not found in /dir/. I have moved the installation to different directories, and moved my php script to different directories as well, but after several hours of searching online, guessing, and trying to make logical choices...I remain in the dark on the configuration problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not give details of what changes you made to the /dir/ location when you moved the installation?

Comment: I had Predis in my home dir, then I tried /etc/ and I tried moving the scripts in several of the directories within Predis. I installed with git, then removed it - a complete purge - then reinstalled with composer, which was supposed to automatically provide the correct configuration. Then repeated many of the moves I mentioned, since composer had not fixed the problem.

Comment: There was an error in the php.ini file. Problem fixed. Not a generalized issue.

Comment: Can you post an answer with how you fixed the error for the benefit of others. Thanks.